# Select requested-only fields from DB with GraphQL and Graphene-Python

Tags: python, database, flask, graphql, graphene-python

I'm building a Python Flask-GraphQL API using Graphene and was wandering if there are any common solutions to requesting only required fields from DB in resolvers.

Let's say there's a request of a basic user info:

```
{
  users {
    id
    name
  }
}
```

And the DB structure for user entity is much more complex and "data-heavy". Now one would obviously try to avoid getting all of the user info from a DB just to filter it on a server side and pass to a client only ids and names requested.

While I'm sure it's a common problem, I was wandering what solutions are considered to be optimal in this case (or is it even possible to make a universal solution not bound to a specific data structure, as there might be some additional data loads and joining involved).

It obveously could be done manually by getting requested field asts from a resolver's info argument.

 
Btw I'm also currently not bound to a specific DB or a data-provider like SQLAlchemy, as I'm trying to wrap my head around the abstract use-case.
Would really appreciate your thoughts and experience on this one. Either abstract or with actual providers and databases.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a complex answer that is SQLAlchemy specific here
[Limiting SQL query to defined fields/columns in Graphene-SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50502781/limiting-sql-query-to-defined-fields-columns-in-graphene-sqlalchemy)

Like stated in some comments there, it's already very complex targeting a particular ORM, so not sure it's possible to answer it in an abstract way.